# pass array list of <LatLng,String> from main activity to another class

Tags: java, android, google-maps, arraylist, latitude-longitude

I have a class called latLng that create an object of LatLng and string,
in MainActivity I created an arraylist of this type and parced json into it.
now I want to pass it to another class but everything I try doesnt work, the program crash down or fill my array in null in the second activity.
here is my code:

latLng.java:

```
public class latLng  {
        LatLng latLng;
        String id;

        latLng( LatLng latLng,String id) {
            this.latLng = latLng;
            this.id = id;
        }

    public String getLatLngId() {
        return id;
    }

    public LatLng getLatLng() {
        return latLng;
    }

}
```

main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  ArrayList<LatLng> locationList=new ArrayList<>();
  ArrayList<latLng> idList=new ArrayList<>();

  Bundle bundle;
    String json;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getJson();
    bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelableArrayList("locationList", locationList);

// Get the coordinates
    locationList = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("locationList");

  }

  public void getJson() {
     json = null;
    try {
      InputStream is = getAssets().open("vehicles-location.json");

      int size = is.available();

      byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

      is.read(buffer);

      is.close();

      json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
      JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
      for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++) {
        JSONObject obj =jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String id=obj.getString("id");
        JSONObject location = obj.getJSONObject("location");
        double x = location.getDouble("lat");
        double y = location.getDouble("lng");
        LatLng m = new LatLng(x, y);
        locationList.add(m);
        latLng l=new latLng(m,id);
        idList.add(l);
      }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();

    }
  }


  public void MapOfVehicles(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapOfVehicles.class);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(intent);
  }

  public void DrawPolygon(View view) {


      Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DrawPolygon.class);
      intent.putExtra("bundle",bundle);
      startActivity(intent);
  }

}
```

drawpolygon.java:

```
public class DrawPolygon extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
  GoogleMap gMap;
  Button btndraw, btndelete,btnlist;
  Polygon polygon = null;
  List<LatLng> latLngList = new ArrayList<>();
  List<Marker> markerList = new ArrayList<>();
  ArrayList<latLng> latLngIdlist = new ArrayList<>();
  ArrayList<String> idlist;
  Boolean created;


  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_draw_polygon);
    btndraw = findViewById(R.id.btndraw );
    btndelete = findViewById(R.id.btndelete );
    btnlist=findViewById(R.id.btnlist);
    created=false;
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    idlist =new ArrayList<>();
    latLngIdlist =(ArrayList<latLng>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("bundle");
```

the error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.os.Bundle cannot be cast to java.io.Serializable
        at android.os.BaseBundle.getSerializable(BaseBundle.java:1233)
        at android.os.Bundle.getSerializable(Bundle.java:1034)
        at android.content.Intent.getSerializableExtra(Intent.java:7516)
        at com.example.u1tema5androidgooglemaps.DrawPolygon.onCreate(DrawPolygon.java:70)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

can somebody help me plss?

Comment: What is the exception you are receiving when the program crashes? Can you provide all the code here, including import statements, please?

Comment: update the question, now it doesnt crash, just give me null to the latLngIdlist

Answer (score 1):

change your latLng  class like this code and send you'r ArrayList by using Intent in main activity.
i don't tested this but i think work.

```
public class latLng  implements Serializable{
    LatLng latLng;
    String id;

    latLng( LatLng latLng,String id) {
        this.latLng = latLng;
        this.id = id;
    }
protected latLng(Parcel in){}


public String getLatLngId() {
    return id;
}

public LatLng getLatLng() {
    return latLng;
}}
```

Comment: tnx, I saw solutions like that on other questions but it didnt work for me.. updates the question with the error msg.